# JTable - Make table header invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to just make the column headers invisible in JTables, as i need to create a matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setTableHeader%28javax.swing.table.JTableHeader%29) says:

> public void setTableHeader(JTableHeader tableHeader)
>
> Sets the tableHeader working with this JTable to newHeader. It is legal to have a null tableHeader.

So, I've not tested it, but I would guess that if the header is set to null, the table won't have any visible header.

Answer (score -1):

```
jTable.getTableHeader().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that you have to add the header to a component after you make the JTable. Aka yourComponent.add(yourTable.getTableHeader()). So to achieve what you're talking about, just don't add the table header to the component.

Comment: "pretty sure" is not good enough: this answer is **wrong**